# Jenkins pipeline - build a job with default input value from another job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline called pipeline1, described by the following Jenkinsfile:

```
node()
{
    def server
    def action

    stage("Configuration")
    {
        def userInput = input(
            id: 'userInput', message: 'Let\'s configure this run !', parameters: [
                choice(choices: "server1\nserver2", name: "server", description: "Which server do you want to use ?"),
                choice(choices: "stop\nstart\nrestart", name: "action", description: "What do you want to do ?")
        ]);

        server = userInput.server;
        action = userInput.action;
    }

    stage("Run")
    {
        echo(server)
        echo(action)
    }
}
```

It asks the user to choice some input in the Configuration stage and just echos them in the Run stage.
I would like to trigger this job from another one and automatically fill the input to avoid human action.
I've tried to use the same syntax we use to build a parametrized job and come to something like this:

```
node()
{
    stage("Run")
    {
        build job: 'pipeline1', wait: true, parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'userInput.server', value: "server1"],
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'userInput.action', value: "stop"]
        ]       
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It does trigger the pipeline1 job, but it wait for the user to fill the input...

**EDIT:** I would like to keep the input feature in pipeline1 instead of having a standard parametrized job.

Do you have any idea to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just delete stage("Configuration"), and use `params.server` and `params.action`.

Comment: @3sky I did not precise that I would like to be able to run my job manually and keep the dynamic input instead of having a standard parametrized job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so, I have got a complete answer for You. Use `properties` in pipeline1 and `if/else` block:

```java
properties([
  parameters([
    choice(name: 'manually',
           description: 'Do you whish to use a user input?',
           choices: 'No\nYes')
  ])
])

node()
{
    def server
    def action

    stage("Configuration") {
        if ( params.useIn == 'Yes' || params.manually == 'Yes' ) {
            def userInput = input(
            id: 'userInput', message: 'Let\'s configure this run !', parameters: [
                choice(choices: "server1\nserver2", name: "server", description: "Which server do you want to use ?"),
                choice(choices: "stop\nstart\nrestart", name: "action", description: "What do you want to do ?")]
            );
            server = userInput.server;
            action = userInput.action;
        } else {
            server = params.server
            action = params.action
        }

    }

    stage("Run")
    {
        echo(server)
        echo(action)
    }
}
```

Job 2 with little changes:

```java
node()
{
    stage("Run")
    {
        build job: 'pipeline1', wait: true, parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'useIn', value: "No"],
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'server', value: "server1"],
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'action', value: "start"]
        ]       
    }
}
```

If You want to run job2, and then use `User Input`, just change `useIn` for `Yes`. So at this moment You can run directly pipeline1 job with User Input:

```java
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Configuration)
[Pipeline] input
Input requested
Approved by 3sky
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run)
[Pipeline] echo
server2
[Pipeline] echo
restart
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

or trigger it by job2, without User Input:

```java
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Configuration)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run)
[Pipeline] echo
server1
[Pipeline] echo
start
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: This is good solution I think, and even better to me you don't need the parameter 'manually' in the first pipeline, then you don't ask the user you have manually trigger the job or an extra parameter to fill.
What I learned here is that you can pass a parameter (useIn) to a job which is not parametrized and this is great !

Comment: I just want to cover all cases :)